# Do not show confirm messagebox if gridview checkbox is not checked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, confirm

I have gridview which has columns of data and a button below the "Apply" to perform some action.

One column in Gridview is a checkbox column. When you select checkboxes and click apply a confirm message pops up asking "Are you sure?" with option of "Yes" and "No".

But if no check box is checked i want to show a popup to user to select a checkbox before performing an action and not show the confirm message popup.

What i have now is if no checkbox is selected the confirm message pops up first and if i press "yes" then an alert message pops up to select atleast one checkbox. If i press cancel no pop up shows.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 if (!IsPostBack)
      {
ApplyAction_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure?');");
      }
    }


 protected void ApplyAction_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  // Gets the selected checkboxes in the gridview 
  ArrayList selectedMachines = new ArrayList();
  GetSelectedMachineIds(selectedMachines);

             if (selectedMachines.Count == 0)
             {
                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script>alert('Please select a machine for the action to be applied');</script>");

                 return;
             }
    // Action to be applied
    }
```

I am trying to avoid the use of postback.

Another question:

Is there a server side confirm message box in asp.net?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try to see those threads

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839558/checkbox-in-gridview

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339767/determining-a-which-checkbox-is-checked-on-a-datagrid-and-updating-db/7340174#7340174


Regards

Comment: nice!! the first link might just help me with the checkbox problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your button visible to false, once check box is checked then you can show the button.
another way is to use javascript to check if checkbox is checked

code behind

```
ApplyAction_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowConfirm();");
```

javascript

```
function ShowConfirm()
{
  //check if checkbox is checked if is checked then display confirm message else display alert message
if( "assumed checkbox is checked"){
return confirm("message here");
}
else{
alert("message here");
}
}
```

Comment: yes this might work.. but i need to know the javascript code of how to check if any checkboxes are checked within the gridview. the code i have is a server side code which wont work with the above java script

Answer (score 1):

try to see this thread

[Checkbox in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839558/checkbox-in-gridview)

[Determining a which checkbox is checked on a datagrid and updating DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339767/determining-a-which-checkbox-is-checked-on-a-datagrid-and-updating-db/7340174#7340174)

Regards

Comment: i tried with the first link, but the javascript there is not working..  it is not checking the checkboxes in the gridview